# Ignoring strange Parsing errors with Xerces

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xerces

I am trying to parse the following url as a DOM Document in Java: http://www.op.org/en/rss-category-home/8.

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
13:51:38,470 ERROR ~ Error processing site Site 1
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "acirc" was referenced, but not declared.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
    at logic.server.RssReader.readRss(RssReader.java:44)
    at logic.server.GatherData.doJobWithResult(GatherData.java:49)
    at logic.server.GatherData.doJobWithResult(GatherData.java:1)
```

I read somewhere that the Xerces parser in the current JRE is has a bug related to this, so downloaded Xerces2 2.11.0, but still have the same problem.

How can I get around this problem. I have no control over the RSS feed itself, but need to parse the XML to process the articles.

My code is:
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

```
    DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = builder.parse(rssUrl.openStream());
    NodeList nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName("item");
    etc. etc.
```

Any help to get around this problem is really appreciated!

**EDIT:**
IF I would try the solution below and add the DTD, where would I do that? The current RSS element is:

```
<rss version="2.0" xml:base="http://www.op.org/en/rss-category-home/8" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" og="http://ogp.me/ns#" rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#" sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#" skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
```

or would I add it to every 'description' element, which containst the XHTML code, something like this? I tried this later solution, but it still gives the same error.

```
<description xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's an error in the XML, why would you want to ignore it? XML parsers are designed to reject bad XML.

It looks like this XML includes an entity reference `&acirc;` but doesn't include the DTD that defines this entity. This is one of the standard XHTML entities, so you can probably repair the XML by adding a reference to the relevant entity declaration DTD modules from XHTML.

Comment: Sure, I can have a look, but as I don't have control of the XML I would need to manually edit the string first before parsing. I was hoping I could avoid that. The problem here is that the reference is in the body of an article in the RSS feed. Most RSS generators just dump the content in between the tags without knowing what is in it.

Comment: Yes, RSS generators are notoriously lax about conformance to XML standards. You need to add a doctype declaration '<!DOCTYPE ...>` before the content (but after any XML declaration). This can either refer to an external DTD, or it can contain the entity definitions inline. Adding a DOCTYPE/DTD is NOT the same as adding a namespace, which is what your example does!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up searching the string for <description> tags and add everything in between as Data. That sorts also any other problems out in the future with bad xhtml as content.

Comment: I added this to the DTD array and it fixed my issue-- <!ENTITY acirc "&#194;">